# RSpec testing a method that uses a form builder element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, helper, formbuilder

I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to implement an Rspec test which can utilize the form builder from rails. Here is what is in my helper:

```
 def render_radio_buttons(answer, label)
    check_these = []
    field = '<div class="radio">'
      label.split(',').each do |option|
        if check_these.include?(option.strip)
          field += answer.radio_button :body, option.strip, checked = true
        else
          field += answer.radio_button :body, option.strip
        end
        field += label_tag option.strip
      end
    field += '</div>'
  end
```

This method is pulling a label field from the database which contains multiple comma separated labels. The answer in this case is the form builder f. How would I go about testing something like this since it needs the form builder?

If you have a better rails method on how to implement this, I would love to know! Thanks for anyone who can help!

Comment: Have you looked into mocking/expectations? `answer` could be a test double that can take in a `radio_button` method, and you could expect it to be called X amount of times with the right arguments. Then you could have that return any old string, and then test your `field` String. You don't really care per se what `.radio_button` returns, because Rails is taking care of that. You more so care about *how* you're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just test the form using Capybara.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Capybara helps you test Rails and Rack applications by simulating how a real user would interact with your app. It is agnostic about the driver running your tests and comes with Rack::Test and Selenium support built in. WebKit is supported through an external gem.

```
describe "the signup process", :type => :request do
  before :each do
    User.make(:email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'caplin')
  end

  it "signs me in" do
    within("#session") do
      fill_in 'Login', :with => 'user@example.com'
      fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
    end
    click_link 'Sign in'
  end
end
```